# Reference Request: de Rham vs. Dolbeault

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi everyone.
I need the following statement:

For a Kahler manifold $X$, the natural map 
$H^n(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^n(X,\mathcal{O})$
(from the sheaf extension) coincides with the Hodge 
projection $\Pr_{0,n}$, up to the  de Rham isomorphism 
and the Dolbeault isomorphism.

Does anybody know a good reference?

P.S. Surely there must be a reference. I am much less interested in proofs: 
I think I know one.

Answer (score 11):

There are lots of references. Mainly every textbook which treats Hodge theory. Try to look at:

- Voisin: Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry. I
- Huybrechts: Complex geometry
- Wells: Differential analysis on complex manifolds
- Griffiths, Harris: Principles of algebraic geometry

There, you will find mainly the proof in the case $n=2$, which is used to prove the Lefschez theorem on $(1,1)$-classes. The general case is a straightforward adaptation of that argument.

Comment: Yes, but to write in a paper 
"The general case is a straightforward adaptation of that"
is not a good manner, is it? And the proofs in 
Griffiths&Harris and Voisin are rather specific for $n=2$. 
(They may be generalized, to be sure, but I wouldn't say it is straightforward. Do not remember about other books). Do not take me wrong, but it  doesn't look like  a very good reference.

Comment: The point is rather that you didn't say you needed this reference for a paper you are writing. In this case, sincerely, you can just state that fact as well-known. No referee would protest! 

Comment: Yes, perhaps you are right. Anyway, it won't do any harm: if the referee insists, then I can write my own proof (with the reference to Griffiths&Harris for a special case).  Of course I shoud have made my purpose clear from the beginning, so we could avoid this bit of confusion. However, I slill hope that someone may give me a reference for a complete proof, which is why I do not accept your answer. Do not mind this. By the way, I have Griffiths&Harris on my bookshelf.

Comment: Of course I don't mind! If I find a complete reference I'll tell you!